# Batch Attributes not on Output

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that is taking an inventory of the X drive. Even though I give it attributes, the Excel file created (or even a text file) does not contain any information besides the file name.

When I run the same command in the command prompt, it gives me the information I want.

How do I create the correct output?

```
@echo off
rem Write folders and details to a text file
echo --------------------------------------------->>C:\users\USER\desktop\InventoryLog.txt
echo Started %date% %time% >>C:\users\USER\desktop\InventoryLog.txt
dir X:\ /s /q /b /ta > C:\users\USER\desktop\Inventory.xls
echo File Contents Appended>>C:\users\USER\desktop\InventoryLog.txt
echo Completed %date% %time% >> C:\users\USER\desktop\InventoryLog.txt
echo ------------------------------------------------- >> C:\users\USER\desktop\InventoryLog.txt
```

Comment: The `/b` switch will only list the filename, nothing else.

Comment: I'm not sure, redirecting text to a `xls` file will do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so there are only a few issues here preventing you from getting the data you want. The main one is the assumption that a .xls file just contains text data. Excel spreadsheets are complex binary data files and can't be created in this way. However, what you can do is export the results to a .csv (Comma-Separated Values) file instead, since Excel can read and import CSV files.

I've adjusted the code below to be easier to manage (putting the paths into variables so they aren't repeated). This works fine on my machine, producing a log file and creating a CSV with a list of all files under `%scan%` (which is X:\ in your case). I also wrapped all the paths in quotes so that any spaces in the folders/filenames won't break your script.

```
@echo off
set log=InventoryLog.txt
set output=Inventory.csv
set scan=X:\
echo ----------------------------------------->> "%log%"
echo Started %date% %time%>> "%log%"
dir "%scan%" /s /q /b /ta > "%output%"
echo File Contents Appended>> "%log%"
echo Completed %date% %time%>> "%log%"
echo ----------------------------------------->> "%log%"
```

Comment: thank you! Your updates worked perfectly when I removed /b per Magoo's comment above. Until I did so though, it was still leaving out the additional info I needed.

Comment: Good to hear! Ah, so you wanted that info too... If you wanted those converted into columns in Excel, there is an import feature where you can specify the width of the columns in your plaintext file, so it's all possible.

Comment: So, if we've been able to solve all your problems, I'd recommend you mark this answer as Accepted by clicking the tick and/or upvote it.

Comment: @moosebiz: please explain, *what* info you need. (edit it into your question instead of a comment)